# android camera error 1001 - what the heck is that?

Tags: android, camera

I've searched all over on the web and I can't find out what that 1001 error is. A few seconds after that I get the camera 100 error but I can't find out what the first error is. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: What ever it was my rollback to an earlier version of my code fixed it but I would still like to know wtf that 1001 error is so I can avoid it in the future.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I encountered this error as well on my S3.  I believe I tracked it down to how the camera preview surface was used by the MediaRecorder.  In my case the preview display was getting reset when I was attempting to start recording.  I solved it by cleaning out my code and just used the calls to set, start and stop the preview display in the SurfaceView implementation below (from the [Android Camera developer guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#camera-preview)):

```
public class CameraPreview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
private Camera mCamera;

public CameraPreview(Context context, Camera camera) {
    super(context);
    mCamera = camera;

    // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the
    // underlying surface is created and destroyed.
    mHolder = getHolder();
    mHolder.addCallback(this);
    // deprecated setting, but required on Android versions prior to 3.0
    mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
}

public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // The Surface has been created, now tell the camera where to draw the preview.
    try {
        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
        mCamera.startPreview();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Error setting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // empty. Take care of releasing the Camera preview in your activity.
}

public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
    // If your preview can change or rotate, take care of those events here.
    // Make sure to stop the preview before resizing or reformatting it.

    if (mHolder.getSurface() == null){
      // preview surface does not exist
      return;
    }

    // stop preview before making changes
    try {
        mCamera.stopPreview();
    } catch (Exception e){
      // ignore: tried to stop a non-existent preview
    }

    // set preview size and make any resize, rotate or
    // reformatting changes here

    // start preview with new settings
    try {
        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
        mCamera.startPreview();

    } catch (Exception e){
        Log.d(TAG, "Error starting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just thought I would add a post here for future reference. This issue bothered me for a long time. 
It turns out that my problem was caused by an incorrect preview size, although the resolution set was obtained from the getSupportedPictureSize method.

So for example you can get the sizes as follows:

```
//first entry in list is 1392x1392 for front facing camera on an S3
List<Camera.Size> supportedPictureSizes = params.getSupportedPictureSizes();
```

Setting this resolution or neglecting to set a picture size alltogether will cause the dreaded error 1001.

If you encounter this on any other device I would recommend trying different picture sizes.

Answer (score 0):

So there was another reason for why I got it on my Galaxy S3. I was using a TextureView to show my camera preview and got this dreaded error when pressing the home button after a successful preview and then entering the app again. In the onResume() function I started up the preview again and found that I had not released the SurfaceTexture instance variable in the onSurfaceTextureDestroyed() function.

I added the release line to this function and it now looks like this and works perfectly:

```
@Override public boolean onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(SurfaceTexture surface) {
    mSurfaceTexture = null; //This was the offending culprit.

    releaseMediaPlayer();
    releaseVideoRecorder();
    releaseCamera();

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, in Samsung S3, the video-size parameter was not set and this led to the 1001 error. Setting the video size on the media recorder using preview size fixed the issue. However, this change may fail on other devices since the parameter may or may not be available/set in all devices. The following code addresses most of the devices:

```
if(params.get("video-size") != null && params.get("video-size").isEmpty()) {
    int videoWidth = params.getPreviewSize().width;
    int videoHeight = params.getPreviewSize().height;
    mediaRecorder.setVideoSize(videoWidth, videoHeight);
} else {
    mediaRecorder.setVideoSize(profile.videoFrameWidth, profile.videoFrameHeight);
}
```