# Camera Error 1001

Tags: java, android, video, android-camera

I have been trying to solve this error for the past couple of days and yet no luck. I'm trying to build an app which records video files for my RTP transport to send to the server. The LOGCAT does not give any other message apart from

`Camera Error 1001` and the message keeps on repeating until I stop the application. The camera initializes and the prepare runs ok. The error is thrown when the MediaRecorder.start() is called.

Here is the code for the video recorder class.

```
MediaRecorder mMediaRec;
Camera mCamera;
Button startRecording = null;
SurfaceView mSurfaceView;
SurfaceHolder mSurfaceHolder;
//CameraPreview mPreview;
boolean isRecording = false;
public static Socket sock;
public Uri filePath;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_media_streamer);
    // Show the Up button in the action bar.
    setupActionBar();
    //addListenerOnButton();

    Log.d(" Streamer On create", "Initializing camera");
    initialize();
    //startRecording();

}

/**
 * Set up the {@link android.app.ActionBar}, if the API is available.
 */
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
private void setupActionBar() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.media_streamer, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        // This ID represents the Home or Up button. In the case of this
        // activity, the Up button is shown. Use NavUtils to allow users
        // to navigate up one level in the application structure. For
        // more details, see the Navigation pattern on Android Design:
        //
        // http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html#up-vs-back
        //
        NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void initialize()
{

    startRecording = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_start);
    mCamera = Camera.open();

    Log.d("Initialization", "Camera opened");
    mSurfaceView = (SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.survace_camera);
    mSurfaceHolder = mSurfaceView.getHolder();
    mSurfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
    //setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
    //mSurfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHholder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    Log.d("Streamer init", "Camera Initialized");
}

protected void startRecording()
{
    //Socket sock = new Socket();

        Log.d("Start recording method","Attempting to start recording");

        try
        {
            mMediaRec = new MediaRecorder();

            mMediaRec.setPreviewDisplay(mSurfaceHolder.getSurface());

            mCamera.unlock();
            mMediaRec.setCamera(mCamera);
            mMediaRec.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
            mMediaRec.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
            mMediaRec.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
            mMediaRec.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.DEFAULT);
            mMediaRec.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.DEFAULT);

            filePath = getOutputMediaFileUri();
            mMediaRec.setOutputFile(filePath.getPath());

            mMediaRec.setMaxFileSize(50000);
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            //mMediaRec.set
            //mCamera.unlock();
            mMediaRec.prepare();
            Log.d("Start recording", "Recorder params set");
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            mMediaRec.start();
            isRecording = true;

} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
        //StreamerBGManager bg = new StreamerBGManager();
        //bg.doInBackground(new String[]{});
catch (InterruptedException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
catch(IllegalStateException e)
{
e.printStackTrace();
releaseMediaRecorder();
releaseCamera();
}

}

protected void stopRecording()
{
    mMediaRec.stop();
    mMediaRec.release();
    mCamera.release();
    releaseMediaRecorder();
    releaseCamera();
    isRecording = false;
}

private void releaseMediaRecorder()
{
    if(mMediaRec != null)
    {
        mMediaRec.reset();
        mMediaRec.release();
        mMediaRec = null;
        mCamera.lock();
        isRecording = false;
    }
}

private void releaseCamera()
{
    if (mCamera != null){
        mCamera.release();        // release the camera for other applications
        mCamera = null;
        isRecording = false;
    }
}

public void toggleRecord(View view)
{
    if(isRecording)
        stopRecording();
    else
        startRecording();
}

/*public void addListenerOnButton()
{

    startRecording.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(isRecording)
                stopRecording();
            else
                startRecording();

        }
    });
}*/

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
        int height) {
}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    if (mCamera != null){
      Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();

      mCamera.setParameters(params);
        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mSurfaceHolder);
            mCamera.startPreview();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Camera not available!",    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        finish();
    }
}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    mCamera.stopPreview();
    mCamera.release();
    //mMediaRec.release();
}
```

Comment: check out this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14493593/android-camera-error-1001-what-the-heck-is-that

Comment: The only difference between my implementation and that is the onSurfaceChanged implementation. So I added that function but it is still giving the same error. All the function calls are in the same order... I don't know what the error is

Comment: Did you find a solution? I also have in some devices the camera error 1001, but no idea of what it really means or how to solve it. Thanks

Comment: No Zhenya, I was stuck on that problem for a long while. My work around it was to call the default camera app, use that to record and get the resulting file location of the recorded video. It was not what I wanted but it works

Comment: Did you try different settings as well? Like encoding or format. And did try setting the preview size explicitly? (That's in Cam's parameters ...) I had some troubles once, where this was a solution. So, just a shot into the blue.

Comment: Not really, I was just using the default settings and I expected the defaults to work before trying something else. Anyway, since I got the alternative to work, I haven't really checked to see what the problem was