# take picture automatically android error take picture failed

Tags: android, eclipse, timer, android-camera, capture

im trying yo take pictures using a counter, when the counter goes to 0 , it has to take the picture, but when the counter is on 0, the application colapses, and says that the function takepicture failed, does anybody know why? . thanks in advance.This is my code;

```
public class CapPhoto extends Activity {

private Camera camera;

private TextView textTimeLeft;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.capphoto);
textTimeLeft=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textTimeLeft);
SurfaceView view = new SurfaceView(this);
camera = Camera.open();
try {
    camera.setPreviewDisplay(view.getHolder()); // feed dummy surface to surface
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
camera.startPreview();
new CountDownTimer(5000, 1000) {

     public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

     }

     public void onFinish() {
         camera.takePicture(null, null, jpegCallBack);
     }
    }
    .start();

}

public void startTimer(View v){

// 5000ms=5s at intervals of 1000ms=1s so that means it lasts 5 seconds
new CountDownTimer(5000,1000){

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        // count finished
        textTimeLeft.setText("Picture Taken");
        camera.takePicture(null, null, null, jpegCallBack);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        // every time 1 second passes
        textTimeLeft.setText("Seconds Left: "+millisUntilFinished/1000);
    }

}.start();
}

Camera.PictureCallback jpegCallBack=new Camera.PictureCallback() {      
public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
    // set file destination and file name

File destination=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"ddddddss.jpg");
    try {
        Bitmap userImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
        // set file out stream
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(destination);
        // set compress format quality and stream
        userImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);        

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
};
}
```

Comment: some time there are issues with phone also so better try on other mobile too and trying add these permissions `<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />`

Answer (score 0):

```
    private TextView textTimeLeft;
private Camera camera;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    textTimeLeft=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textTimeLeft);
    SurfaceView view = new SurfaceView(this);
    camera = Camera.open();
    try {
        camera.setPreviewDisplay(view.getHolder()); // feed dummy surface to surface
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    camera.startPreview();


}
Camera.PictureCallback jpegCallBack=new Camera.PictureCallback() {      
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        // set file destination and file name
        File destination=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"ddddddss.jpg");
        try {
            Bitmap userImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
            // set file out stream
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(destination);
            // set compress format quality and stream
            userImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);        

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
};
public void startTimer(View v){

    new CountDownTimer(10000, 1000) {//CountDownTimer(edittext1.getText()+edittext2.getText()) also parse it to long

         public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
             textTimeLeft.setText("Seconds Left: "+millisUntilFinished/1000);
         }

         public void onFinish() {
             camera.takePicture(null, null, null, jpegCallBack);
         }
        }
        .start();
    }
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    camera.release();
}
}
```

Change your code to this.

Add the following permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

and my activity_main.xml is

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonStartTimer"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Start Timer"
    android:onClick="startTimer" />
<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/textTimeLeft"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: thanks a lot, i applied your code , but it still throws the error java.lang.RuntimeException: takePicture failed :(

Comment: have you added permissions for camera and for writing in external storage? I have tried this code and it works for me.

Comment: i already have all the permissions on my manifest file :(  im testing a samsung galaxy S4 , i don't know whether the phone is the reason of the failure

Comment: I didn't exactly find the problem with your code. Your code is not working for me either. Just copy the above activity.

Comment: thanks for your help!, now the application does not stop working , but it throws the error 1001

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14493593/android-camera-error-1001-what-the-heck-is-that

Comment: im gonna check the link that you just shared, thanks for your patience and help :)

Answer (score 0):

i think you should release the camera resource onDestroy() 
not onPause(), an error is when you leave the app and come back the onPause() method is trigerred and camera is released then it gives an error, other than that everything seems to be running fine