# Some picture sizes causing Camera.takePicture() to fail

Tags: android, android-camera

**Summary:** Explicitly setting the camera picture size to a supported size causes callbacks not to be called after Camera.takePicture() is called, for some picture sizes.

**Details:**

I am working on a simple camera app that uses the Camera API to capture images. It follows the guidelines described in the Camera class documentation, and works reliably on a variety of devices.

After calling Camera.open() the app calls camera.getParameters() to get a Camera.Parameters object and then calls this object's getSupportedPictureSizes(). It iterates over the supported picture sizes and chooses one size pair that fits some criteria. It then calls setPictureSize(), passing-in the chosen width and height. Finally it sets the camera parameters by calling camera.SetParameters(), passing-in the Camera.Parameters object.

I am encountering problems with the HTC Desire 620. One of the supported picture sizes reported on this device is 1184x1184. If I set this picture size and then call camera.takePicture(), none of the callbacks (shutter, raw, or jpeg) are ever called and the camera object appears to be left in an invalid state. If I explicitly set the picture size to any other supported size (square or rectangular aspect ratio) then the callbacks are called. But for 1184x1184 they aren't.

Has anyone encountered anything like this? Is there any way to know in advance whether a supported picture size is going to cause this type of problem? What am I missing here?

Edit: typo

Comment: So the code works fine on other sizes?

Comment: "Has anyone encountered anything link this?" -- if by "link", you mean "like", yes, I have encountered this a fair bit. "Is there any way to know in advance whether a supported picture size is going to cause this type of problem?" -- not in advance as far as I am able to tell. "What am I missing here?" -- a philosophy of robust quality control on the part of Android device manufacturers, particularly those responsible for the camera APIs.

Comment: @Braim Yes, it works with all the 34 supported picture sizes except 1184x1184.

Comment: I got interested because I am writing a camera app too. didn't encounter a similar issue on the LG G3 I use for testing.

Comment: @Braim I've tested it on a wide variety of devices (including other HTCs) and this is the first time I've encountered this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have *HTC Desire 620*, so I cannot verify your findings. But I have seen quite a few devices in my carreer of Android camera development. The issue you describe is one of the scenarios that do happen. I would prefer to forget about the days Honeycomb 2.3, where each supported device needed its own set of workarounds. But even later things were never perfect.

For example, Galaxy Nexus device claimed to support QVGA with getSupportedPreviewSizes(). But it did not. Setting preview size to 320x240 still produced 640x480 byte array in the onPreviewFrame().

Lots of bugs are related to video vs. preview sizes. Some bugs pop up in Portrait orientation. And so on.

Just as you noticed, quite often, the problematic settings result simply in callbacks never arriving. But it is still a good practice to always wrap `camera.setParameters()` and other camera calls with try…catch.

Keep your eye on strange dependencies: e.g. night scene cannot coexist with continuous focus. Unfortunately, the Camera API as we know it can not provide such information.

If you browse through opensource projects that deal with variety of camera devices, you will find that they keep track of unsuccessful settings (parameters sets), and only fail on these once.

**Update** one of the non-obvious dependencies which I came across, was between set preview size and set picture size. E.g. when the latter was 16:9 aspect ratio, the picture could not be set 4:3.

**Update** and *[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26070960/192373)* is a story of a wrong 'supported' picture size in Samsung Galaxy S3. Using it leads to camera error 1001.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I am considering using a timer to catch the cases where the callback never arrives, and add the picture size to an "ignore list". I'd prefer to handle the problem in a way that isn't visible to the user, but, since the camera object is left in an invalid state, I need to detach it from the surface holder - and this causes a visible glitch. Do you have any pointers to code that handles this type of issue in a clean way?

Comment: When you call `takePicture()` for **1184x118**, does the preview surface freeze?

Comment: Then maybe you can simply change camera parameters without interrupting preview? For the UX, it will look like this picture takes much longer than usual, that's all.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work. I can successfully change the picture size to a known-good value, but when I call Camera.takePicture() again a Java.Lang.RuntimeException is thrown with the message "takePicture failed".I think that the camera instance is in a state where it is unusable.

Comment: Uff, this is painful. But anyway, your end-user will have to experience this pain only once. If you want to go an extra mile, you can send keep track of such situations (Crashlytics may be a good tool for that), and maintain a centralized repository of "known problematic settings", given the device make and OS version.

Answer (score 0):

This is my code, that i use to take pictures, and save them in a database, without changing its quality. Maybe it isn't what you are looking for, but it could help you.

First you need this variables:

```
 private static final int CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST = 2500;
private Rect Padding = new Rect(-1,-1,-1,-1);
private Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
private Bitmap rotatedBitmap = null;
private Bitmap bm = null;
private Bitmap scaledBitmap= null;
private ExifInterface exif ;
private int rotation=0;
private final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
```

Then set the request, from a button, activity or fragment, depending on your app (Mine uses a button)

```
btn_camera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View view) {

              Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
              startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);

          }
    }
    );
```

Now as I am requesting the CAMERA
_PIC_REQUEST from a Fragment i implement this code on the OnActivityResult()

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST)
        if (data != null) {
        imageuri = data.getData();
        //Bitmap image = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");

        try {
            options.inSampleSize = 2;
            exif = new ExifInterface(getRealPathFromURI(imageuri));
            rotation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);
            rotation = exifToDegrees(rotation);

            bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(
                    getActivity().getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageuri),Padding,options);

            scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bm, 400,400, true);

            if (rotation != 0)
            {matrix.postRotate(rotation);}
            //matrix.postRotate(180);
            rotatedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(scaledBitmap , 0, 0, scaledBitmap .getWidth(), scaledBitmap .getHeight(), matrix, true);

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        mIvFoto.setImageBitmap(rotatedBitmap);


     }
 }
```

The rotation and the matrix are for scaling the pic taken, to an ImageView, so i can take a preview of the photo, before saving it. That doesn't affect the quality of the pic. It's just for the preview bitmap. So in the ScaledBitmap variable as you can see, when CreatingScaledBitmap, i place the dimensions of the pic, to 400,400 you can place the dimensions of the pic you want you get, be sure to rotate the bitmap, so you can get the picture right, even if you take the photo in portrait mode.

Finally the methods for rotating and getting the picture from the Path that the camera saves it.

```
private static int exifToDegrees(int exifOrientation) {
    if (exifOrientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90) { return 90; }
    else if (exifOrientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180) {  return 180; }
    else if (exifOrientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270) {  return 270; }
    return 0;
}

private String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentURI) {
    String result;
    Cursor cursor =getActivity().getContentResolver().query(contentURI, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor == null) { // Source is Dropbox or other similar local file path
        result = contentURI.getPath();
    } else {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA);
        result = cursor.getString(idx);
        cursor.close();
    }
    return result;
}
```

I hope this may help you.

Comment: Like I said, the app works well on a wide variety of devices. The problem is with setting a explicit picture size, which your code doesn't seem to do. But thanks for responding and its always useful to see how other people do things.